# Thunderbird constantly requires 'allow this installation' confirmation

Tags: linux, email, debian, thunderbird

I use Thunderbird 60.7.1 (debian 9) and add-on MinimizeToTray-reanimated. The problem is every time when I start Thunderbird I have the following message. I mark `allow this installation`  after which I have to restart Thunderbird. After restarting everything is ok and MinimizeToTray is working. However, when I start Thunderbird next time I see the message again. How to fix it?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/minimizetotray-reanimated/

> On some systems (Windows or GNU / Linux and maybe MacOS), Thunderbird
>   can enter a reinstallation loop: at each opening, the addon is
>   reinstalled and does not appear in the addon manager list. This
>   problem is not resolved because the cause is still not identified. In
>   this case please download the version under development (* dev.xpi)
>   that corrects this problem on Github:
>   https://github.com/ysard/mintrayr/releases